# Mapping a grammar to a graph - Relation of Terminal Symbol and Node Coverage in Software Testing

Tags: graphs, formal-grammars, software-testing, testing

I am currently trying map a grammar to a graph in the context of syntax- and graph-based testing.
However, until now I haven't had an enlightenment how **would I map non-terminals and terminals to nodes and edges in relation to the following quote**?

> ... [Terminal Symbol Coverage] and [Production Derivation Coverage]* can be rewritten to be equivalent to node coverage and edge coverage on the graph that represents the grammar.
> From: Ammann, Paul, and Jeff Offutt. Introduction to Software Testing, Cambridge University Press, 2008.

*Where derivation coverage means that every terminal and non-terminal symbol is used at least once.

---

Some ideas:

- Terminal symbols have to be nodes.
- Non-terminals cannot be nodes, else node coverage would imply derivation coverage.
- Are non-terminals then edges, but how would the graph look like, what other nodes need to be there?

Maybe as example the following grammar where X (and I think) C, are not necessary to cover for terminal symbols/nodes only.

```
A::= B"@"B"."B 
B::= BL | L | C | X
X ::= L
C::= B | B"."B 
L::= "a" | "b" | "c"
```

How do I have to construct the graph so that the two principles align? What are the nodes and edges?

Comment: I suggest you pick one of "[Terminal Symbol Coverage] and [Production Derivation Coverage]" to ask about, and define what that problem is, in the question.  The algorithm/graph might be different for each.